# Visual Studio 2022 on Windows with MAUI does not connect to Mac

Tags: xcode, visual-studio, maui

I am using Visual Studio 2022 v. 17.4.4 on Windows.
My Mac has XCode 14.1.

When I am working with a Xamarin Forms project, I have no problem.
When I am working with a MAUI project, connecting to the Mac fails.
To try again, I have to close Visual Studio and reopen it, because the "Connect" button gets disabled.

I have downloaded and installed xamarin.ios-16.1.1.27.pkg and xamarin.mac.9.0.0.27.pkg on the Mac, but I get the same results.
On a suggestion from a comment below, I installed VS 17.5 Preview (17.5 build 1728) on the Mac, but I get the same results.

Sometimes I get an error, and sometimes I don't. When I do get the error, it says:

```
"The Xcode version installed on the Mac (14.1) is not compatible with this version of Visual Studio. This may cause unexpected warnings or errors when building and deploying iOS projects. Please install Xcode '0.0'."
```

One thing that jumps out to me is it is asking me to install **XCode 0.0**.

Here is the Xamarin log when I try to connect:

```
Checking host configuration for connecting to <mac's IP address>...
Checking SSH configuration...
Current SSH Key File: C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Xamarin\MonoTouch\id_xma.pub
Initializing environment...
Checking available disk space...
Checking Mono installation...
Checking host configuration for connecting to '<mac's IP address>'...
Host '<mac's IP address>' is configured correctly
Starting connection to '<mac's IP address>'...
Checking Broker 17.4.0.312 installation...
Starting Broker 17.4.0.312 in port 59545...
Broker 17.4.0.312 started successfully
Starting connection to '<mac's IP address>'...
SSH connection to '<mac's IP address>' has been established...
Starting registered Agents: IDB 17.4.0.312...
Starting IDB 17.4.0.312...
Checking IDB 17.4.0.312 installation...
Starting IDB 17.4.0.312 in port 59545...
IDB 17.4.0.312 started successfully
IDB 17.4.0.312 started
Starting registered Agents: ...
The Agents have been started successfully
Performing server validations against '<mac's IP address>'...
dotnet validation completed
The dotnet SDK is already installed. Version: '7.0.102'
Sdk packs found: 
dotnet validation completed
The dotnet ios workload is already installed. Version: '16.1.1477'
Initializing IDB environment...
Server Settings:
- mlaunch path: 
- Xcode version: 14.1
- Xcode path: /Applications/Xcode.app

Starting disconnection from <mac's IP address>...
Validating Mac operating system version compatibility...
Starting disconnection from <mac's IP address>...
The connection to '<mac's IP address>' has been finished
```

I have searched online for countless hours, but found no solution.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/pair-to-mac?view=net-maui-7.0

Comment: Thanks. but I know how to connect to a Mac. As I said above, It works fine if I'm working with a Xamarin Forms project.

Comment: The requirements for Xamarin and MAUI are different.  The page suggests installing VS Mac Preview on the Mac, which you said you have not done

Comment: I installed VS on the Mac, and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft released Visual Studio 2022 17.5 Preview 6 which cured the problem, but MAUI still doesn't work.